# UITableViewCell ignore autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I tried everything since few days, even I tried use automaticDimension, and estimatedRowHeight = 44, none of them luck. I am new to UITableView and I am tried to practice with it. I look everywhere in stackoverflow, etc and no luck. I am not sure what did I doing wrong with this code below.

In view controller:

```
reminder_tableview.frame = view.bounds
reminder_tableview.allowsSelection = false
reminder_tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 44
reminder_tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
reminder_tableview.register(reminder_tableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reminderList")
reminder_tableview.delegate = self
reminder_tableview.dataSource = self
tab2_body.addSubview(reminder_tableview)
```

And in the extension for UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {return UITableView.automaticDimension}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {return 50.0}
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {return reminder_category_user.count}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if reminder_tableisready == true {
            let category_name = UILabel()
            category_name.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 80, height: 50)
            category_name.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
            category_name.text = reminder_category_user[section]
            category_name.textColor = UIColor.red

            let num_of_reminder = UILabel()
            num_of_reminder.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - 75, y: 0, width: 70, height: 50)
            num_of_reminder.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
            num_of_reminder.text = String(reminder_final_table[section].count)
            num_of_reminder.textAlignment = .right
            num_of_reminder.textColor = UIColor.red

            let headerView = UIView()
            headerView.addSubview(category_name)
            headerView.addSubview(num_of_reminder)
            return headerView
        } else {
            return UIView()
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if reminder_tableisready == true {
            return reminder_final_table[section].count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reminderList") as! reminder_tableCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 15/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.frame.size.height = 100
        cell.textLabel?.text = reminder_final_table[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].pre_title
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()

        let getdatefromdatedue = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(reminder_final_table[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].pre_datedue))
        let duedateformat = DateFormatter()
        duedateformat.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy\nh:mm a"

        if reminder_final_table[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].pre_datedue != 0 {
            cell.layoutMargins.right = 160
            cell.reminder_date_due.text = "Date Due\n\(duedateformat.string(from: getdatefromdatedue))"
        } else {
            cell.reminder_date_due.text = ""
        }
        cell.reminder_date_due.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.reminder_date_due.textAlignment = .right
        cell.reminder_date_due.numberOfLines = 4
        cell.reminder_date_due.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)

        return cell
    }
}

class reminder_tableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var reminder_date_due = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        reminder_date_due.frame = CGRect(x: reminder_tableview.frame.width - 155, y: 0, width: 150, height: 66)
        addSubview(reminder_date_due)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd highly **recommend against using magic values** for your frames (and in general), because if you want to support all screen sizes it will quickly get out  of control.

Also, since you're pre-calculating all your frames, you're actually not using Auto Layout.

Apple has introduced `Auto Layout` with a constraint-based behaviour so that you don't have to do all of the frame calculation work manually for every screen size. `Auto Layout` will dynamically calculate the size and position for all your views depending on the constraints/anchors you've set, whether it is by using Storyboards or programatically.

I also see in your code that you're using a `reminder_tableview` variable thats refers to your `UITableView` and makes me think you're using your table view as a global property: something which you should be avoiding at all cost.

For naming properties or methods, the best practice would be to use **Camel Case, as it will make your code easier to read and understand**. Camel Case is when you start a name with a lowercase letter, then capitalize the first letter of second and all subsequent words, for example:

```
let reminderTableIsReady = false
var reminderDueDateLabel: UILabel?
func scheduleNewReminder() {}
// ...
```

And the common accepted way for naming classes, enums or structs would be **Upper Camel Case**:

```
class ReminderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {}
```

Now to go back to your code, I refactored and made a minimal version of it for you to see it how it would work with Auto Layout and constraints, for the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`.

I didn't add everything from your code but I think you can easily do the rest by yourself:

**ReminderViewController:**

```
import UIKit

// You don't have to use this Date extension below, but this will improve the performances by keeping only one formatter instance, since you will be reusing it in all your UITableViewCell:
extension Date {

    static let formatter = DateFormatter()

    func formatted() -> String {
        Date.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a"
        return Date.formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

struct Reminder {
    let dueDate: TimeInterval
}

class ReminderViewController: UIViewController {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "reuseIdentifier"
    private var reminders = [[Reminder]]()
    private let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ReminderTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        reminders = // ... Set your data here
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension ReminderViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
}

extension ReminderViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return reminders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section > reminders.count {
            return 0
        }
        return reminders[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ReminderTableViewCell
        let reminder = reminders[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: reminder.dueDate)
        if reminder.dueDate > 0 {
            cell.dueDateLabel.text = "Due Date: \(date.formatted())"
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ReminderTableViewCell:**

```
class ReminderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let dueDateLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        dueDateLabel.textColor = .red
        dueDateLabel.textAlignment = .right
        dueDateLabel.numberOfLines = 4
        dueDateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)
        contentView.addSubview(dueDateLabel)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        dueDateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dueDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        dueDateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        dueDateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        dueDateLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still not working. Date Due label more height than content view. The content view is stubborn stuck at height 44.

Comment: Hey, I figured out. You're very helpfully. Thank you. I will make sure I learn Camel Case better. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear you could manage to get it work, have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit incomplete, I assume your issue is `reminder_date_due` label is not getting the layout as expected.

First of all you are not using autolayout, you are using frame based layout system.

You're setting the label's frame in init but at that point layout engine hasn't properly calculated the parent view's frame hence `reminder_tableview.frame.width` is invalid.

Try setting label's frame in `func layoutSubviews()`.